# Using Regular expression to modify the xml file

Tags: javascript, regex, xml

i have a xml file to which i need to

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><ns0:TradeMessage xmlns:ns0="http://aptp.accenture.com/BuySell">
    <SecuritiesTrade>
        <Direction>BUY</Direction>
        <Other Tags>
        </other Tags>
 </SecuritiesTrade>
</ns0:TradeMessage>
```

Now what i want is to use a regular expression and remove only this tag:

what regular expression should i use so that the output is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <SecuritiesTrade>
        <Direction>BUY</Direction>
        <Other Tags>
        </other Tags>
 </SecuritiesTrade>
```

Comment: Use proper XML parser instead of regex..

Comment: NO i need to use regular expression and replace the tags by null. is there any option i can do that. Also the contents in the <ns.. > may change

Comment: javascript. i have already used some code to remove few of thing(see below):$XMLStr = $XMLStr.replace(/^<\?xml\s+version\s*=\s*(["'])[^\1]+\1[^?]*\?>/, "").trim(); to remove the start line <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>.   Need the rest to remove the ns tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
<\/?ns0:TradeMessage(?:[^>]*)>
```

The idea is that we match an open tag:                 `<`
followed by an optional close slash:                       `\/?`
followed by ns0:TradeMessage:                             `ns0:TradeMessage`
followed by any characters other than a close tag: `(?:[^>]*)` 
followed by a close tag:                                          `>`

```js
var str = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><ns0:TradeMessage\n"+ "xmlns:ns0=\"http://aptp.accenture.com/BuySell\">\n"+
"    <SecuritiesTrade>\n"+
"        <Direction>BUY</Direction>\n"+
"        <Other Tags>\n"+
"        </other Tags>\n"+
" </SecuritiesTrade>\n"+
"</ns0:TradeMessage>";
       
var regex = /<\/?ns0:TradeMessage(?:[^>]*)>/g;

alert(str.replace(regex,""));
```

Here's a another [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iR8wO3/1)

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved :)